# I need assistance with radio button in php

Tags: php

I am trying to make it so that when I select on a certain radio button it will change the font in the textbox where the user will enter words. How do I make it so it will change the font when I select a specific radio button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    -->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Funky Font Message</title>
  <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> </head>
<div id="pageContainer">
  <form>
    <h2>Please select a font and enter a message:</h2>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="ChunkRed"> Chunk Red
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="DecoBlue" checked> Deco Blue
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Animals"> Animals
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="ElegantRed"> Elegant Red
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="Funky"> Funky
    <input type="radio" name="font" value="TapePunch"> TapePunch
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="message" required size="50" value="The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php if (!empty($_GET[ 'message'])) { $message=$ _GET[ 'message']; for ($i=0 ; $i < strlen($message); ++$i) { $char=substr($message, $i, 1); if ($char !=" " ) { echo "<img src='/sandvig/Images/Alphabet/deco/blue/{$char}1.gif'>\n" ; } else { echo "<br />\n"; } } } ?> </form>
</div>

<body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, javascript.  jQuery makes the effect you desire a breeze.

Comment: well wait, do you want the font to change dynamically as the user is entering their message?  or are you just having the user declare the font to be used in post processing?

Comment: you could use just css

Comment: When the user clicks the radio button they desire and then type something in the text box. Then click the submit button. I want the font to change when the user clicks submit

Comment: FYI, `substr($message, $i, 1)` can be written as `$message[$i]`. You can also write `foreach (str_split($message) as $char)`

Comment: `$ _GET[ 'message']` that's an issue if it's part of your real code. Plus, you should get into the habit of accepting answers if any solved your other questions. This also informs everyone that solutions were found and won't leave your questions as unanswered. The site does go both ways you know. If you expect help, you should reward those who help you by accepting their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is more or less what you are trying to do but like I say you can do this in just css...this just sets colours but you could change all manner of properties like this.

I guess however having seen the comment that you wish the font to change once a user hits `submit` that this is not what you were attempting afterall.

```
    <style>
        input[value="ChunkRed"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:red!important;
        }
        input[value="DecoBlue"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:blue!important;
        }
        input[value="Animals"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:green!important;
        }
        input[value="ElegantRed"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:purple!important;
        }
        input[value="Funky"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:yellow!important;
            background:black;
        }
        input[value="TapePunch"]:checked ~ input[type="text"]{
            color:white!important;
            background:blue;
        }
    </style>

    <form>
        <h1>Stack - pure css</h1>
        <h2>Please select a font and enter a message:</h2><br>
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="ChunkRed"> Chunk Red
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="DecoBlue" checked> Deco Blue
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Animals"> Animals
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="ElegantRed"> Elegant Red
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="Funky"> Funky
        <input type="radio" name="font" value="TapePunch"> TapePunch<br><br>

        <input type="text" name="message" required size="50" value="The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="text" <?php if (isset($_GET['font'])) echo "style='font-family: \"{$_GET['font']}\";'"; ?> name="message" required size="50" value="The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog" autofocus>
```